# SQLite error winOpen - The current process has used all of its system allowance of handles for Window Manager objects

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-ce

My C#.net application is deployed in WinCE environment. We use SQLLite as database. Sometimes, on leaving application idle overnight- no activity, get the following error-

> SQLite error (14): os_win.c:43373: (1158) winOpen(\MyDB.db3) - The
>   current process has used all of its system allowance of handles for
>   Window Manager objects.

Any inputs why this would happen? Code described below.

```
 using (var sqlConnection= this.GetConnection(activeLocation))
    {

     SQLiteCommand command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
     command.CommandText = query;
     var reader = command.ExecuteReaderExtend();

     try
     {
        // Code written to Collect data from reader
     } 
     catch (System.Exception ex)
     {
        throw ex;
     }
     finally
     {
        this.CloseReader(reader);
        if (sqlConnection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
           sqlConnection.Close();
         }
     }
  }
```